# Get amount from response in gateway-independent way

Tags: php, omnipay

When using Omnipay, is it possible to retrieve the *processed* amount from the response in a gateway-independent way?

For example, when using the Stripe gateway, I would `authorize` a payment as follows (`authorize` is an example, this question applies to all gateway methods):

```
$options = [
    'amount' => '10.00',
    'currency' => 'EUR',
];

$response = $gateway->authorize($options)->send();

if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    $data = $response->getData();

    $amount = $data['amount'] / 100;
}
```

Since Stripe works in cents, I'm forced to divide by `100` to get the amount in the same unit as I specified it, in the request.

However, not all gateways work in cents, which means the code above is not gateway-independent. Also, the `amount` parameter might not even be called the same in other gateways.

Note: I need to retrieve the *processed* amount to verify that it's the same as the requested amount. This would be unnecessary if omnipay would guarantee that they are the same, but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, OmniPay 2.x does not focus on normalisation of data that is returned by the gateways. You are very much left on your own to look at the raw data and apply your knowledge about what it means.

OmniPay 3.x does have an [AmountInterface](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/blob/3.0/src/AmountInterface.php) that standardises the way amounts are handled (no longer a string or integer or float), so there is an `Amount` class that represents the processed amount. Using the `Amount` class for both input (request messages) and output (parsed response messages) now means there is no ambiguity in what the amount means.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/403) on omnipay and this has since been implemented for 3.0. Maybe you can update your answer to make this clearer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Cool - I missed that one :-)